# Delete free apps from Play Store library

Tags: google-play-store, filter

I want to delete free apps from my Play Store library. I don't want to remove paid apps because I obviously paid for them so that means that they are useful to me in some way or another. However, I have accumulated a list of around 500 apps, of which 90% aren't used anymore.

The problem is, I can't remember which apps I paid for and which not. When I click on each app, I sometimes don't see that I purchased them, just the standard "Install" button.

Is there a way to filter out paid apps from my library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use both a PC and your mobile for this solution.

Using your PC, visit [your Play Store's order history](https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory?purchaseFilter=apps). It would list only those apps you have bought so far. Now, in your Play Store app, go to Account (rightwards swipe from the left edge) → Library.

Compare the two lists. The ones which would not match would be the free ones.

This is not user-friendly but should get the job done nonetheless.

Comment: Ok thank you, this will do I guess. Still frustrating that something like this isn't easier. Not your fault though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need this. Google Play will register what's in your library, so if you paid for it (or got it at a limited "sale" for free), you'll be able to install it later when you need it.

Just make sure you don't delete any paid app from a 3rd-party store (although 3rd-party stores tend to have a similar feature), or delete anything you don't need from Google Play.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to remove ANY paid apps from my library because I have no way of knowing which ones I bought and which not later on. I would just end up downloading free apps or buy a new one despite me having already bought one